# How do I switch branch in main repo and automatically update a submodule to the appropriate branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo with a submodule. I have 2 branches in the main repo and in the submodule. In the 'main' branch of the repo, my .gitmodules file references the 'main' branch of the submodule. In the 'second' branch of the repo, my .gitmodules file references the 'second' branch of the submodule.

When I switch between branches in the main repo, I would like the submodule to update to the correct branch.

I am using the following command:
`git checkout --recurse-submodules second`

This updates the main branch and the .gitmodules file now references the 'second' branch for the submodule, but the submodule remains in the 'main' branch.

I have also tried: `git submodule update --init --remote --recursive`

What do I still need to do?